# How do i cache bust with Django's staticfiles?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a webpage which includes an image. I wish to cache bust that image using the ? technique. However, staticfiles encodes questionmarks as '%3F', so the path is no longer correct.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'poll/img/test.jpg?v2' %}">
```

Gets compiled as.

```
<img src="/static/poll/img/test.jpg%3Fv2">
```

There is no `test.jpg%3Fv2` file. So it doesn't show. Using `static` it works fine.

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'poll/img/test.jpg?v2' %}">
```

Get's compiled as expected. I want to use `staticfiles` rather than `static` as I serve my static files from a cloud service. Is there a way to prevent the encoding of my string path or a workaround of the problem?

Comment: I would have told you to use the [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) but it is not possible as you are using a cloud service. Does your cloud service provide a similar cache busting solution?

Comment: I use S3 and cloudfront. I could purge the records and reupload the uploaded filename with same name, hoping that the newer version would be served to all and no browser would keep caching the older version. Ignore the far future cache expiration. That seems risky and unreliable. I would much prefer just to keep the "?" which I know would produce a fully satisfactory result.

 I use `django-compressor`, which produces a unique name for css and js files. Sadly it does not support images.

Comment: Ok, I guess you could write a custom template tag using the  `staticfiles`'s template tag code under the hood but handling GET parameters the way you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the encoding either write your own version of the static tag or simply move the parameters beyond the tag.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'poll/img/test.jpg' %}?v2">
```